# Moreh Nevuchim Arabic-Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, arabic, rambam, books-generally

Does anyone know of a Hebrew/Arabic online or in print?

Comment: Closely related later question: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6183

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17495

Answer (score 6):

Judeo-Arabic edition: http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/index.php?table_name=seforim_database&function=details&where_field=id&where_value=217

An Arabic edition is available for download (warning: 23 Megabytes) at http://sepehr.mohamadi.name/download/DelalatolHaerin.pdf

This was linked from Arabic Wikipedia: http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86

Comment: Well, done, يوسف!

Answer (score 3):

You mean an edition that has both the original Judeo-Arabic and a Hebrew translation?

I've seen [Mosad HaRav Kook's edition of Rambam's Sefer HaMitzvos "mekor v'targum"](http://www.mosadharavkook.com/store/item2.php?id=248) -- with the Arabic and Hebrew side-by-side.  I don't know if they have the Moreh also.

According to Wikipedia, the late [R' Yosef Qafih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) (pronounced *Kapach*) published an edition of Moreh Nevuchim with the original Arabic and his Hebrew translation; [this Qafih edition is probably your best bet](http://www.mosadharavkook.com/store/item2.php?id=202), though I can't tell from the description if it has the Arabic too.  [Here's a different translation](http://www.mosadharavkook.com/store/item2.php?id=200), again unclear if it contains the original Arabic.

A quick glance at hebrewbooks.org has only older, European editions.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok...how about an Arabic/English copy?

Comment: The Kapach Mosad HaRav Kook edition linked to is Hebrew-only. I have the same edition and the 480 page version doesn't include the Arabic. The Dr. Kaufman version doesn't contain the Arabic either, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

Another online Arabic version hosted at the National Library in Jerusalem:
http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/mss/html/heb1458_h.htm