# English translation of Rambam's Moreh Nevuchim (Maimonides' Guide for the Perplexed) on the Internet?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, internet, jewish-books, rambam, english

Is there an English translation on the Internet of Rambam's philosophic treatise on Jewish philosophy, Moreh Nevuchim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An online translation can be found [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp003.htm).

Comment: @AdamMosheh [This](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/20.pdf) is the same translation, but in PDF, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

guide for the perplexed can be found in the [christian classics etheral library](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/maimonides/guide.html).

Comment: this is the same edition as the one in this answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17496/603

Comment: @Menachem your link redirects to this q n a.

Comment: @barlop: Another answer on this page

Comment: @Menachem Do you realise that norman's link also contains the whole thing in 3 different formats. plaintext, pdf, and online. The PDF or text one allows you to easily search the whole thing for anything.   BTW here is another link of it on one page  https://archive.org/details/the_guide_for_the_perplexed   and a direct link https://ia902306.us.archive.org/20/items/the_guide_for_the_perplexed/the_guide_for_the_perplexed.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I found this online which is the [Moshe Friedlander (1903) translation

[The Guide for the Perplexed
by Moses Maimonides
translated by M. Friedländer
[1903]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/) which also includes a zipped version for download.

Another location [for the 1904 edition](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed_(1904))

Answer (score 0):

The Guide of the Perplexed, 2 Volumes, by Moses Maimonides (Author), Shlomo Pines (Translator), Leo Strauss (Introduction), University Of Chicago Press:
[https://www.amazon.com/Guide-Perplexed-Vol-1/dp/0226502309/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226502309)
[https://www.amazon.com/Guide-Perplexed-Vol-2/dp/0226502317/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226502317)

Comment: The question was about online translations not published translations.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Sefaria version of the Friedlander translation most useful:

https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed?lang=en