# Moreh Nevuchim Online

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, internet, rambam

Is the Hebrew text of Maimonides' Moreh HaNevuchim available for free online? (In text form rather than Pdf).

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17495/english-translation-of-rambams-moreh-nevuchim-maimonides-guide-for-the-perple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hebrew:
Ibn Tibon, Schwartz, and Kapach:
http://mobile.tora.ws/

Schwartz:
http://press.tau.ac.il/perplexed/toc.asp

Kapach: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/more/shaar-2.htm

English (Friedlander)
http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/

Ibn Tibon and Friedlander in parallel: http://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed

If you're looking to pick a single one for Hebrew I would personally go with Kapach, but that's *completely* personal opinion with nothing to actually back it up. My reasoning is simply that Kapach is perhaps the greatest Rambam scholar since Rambam himself. He dedicated his life to studying the Rambam, and his knowledge of Arabic and Judeo-Arabic was excellent.

Comment: My personal inclination is also to go with Kapach, a.k.a. Qafih. BTW do you know how to download the entire text simultaneously, from any of these sites (particularly those woth the Kapach ed.?